# How to filter objects in django based on json field where a key is list and based on number of list items mathched for each object?

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have a an object named canditade.

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    skills = models.JSONField()
```

I have created objects like this

```
Candidate.objects.create(name='mark',skills={'list':{'name':'python'},
                            {'name':'java'},
                            {'name':'sql'},
                                                    {'name':'django'}
})


Candidate.objects.create(name='jeremy',skills={'list':{'name':'python'},
                            {'name':'java'},
                            {'name':'sql'},
                                                    {'name':'django'}
})


Candidate.objects.create(name='jeremy',skills={'list':{'name':'python'},
                            {'name':'java'},
                                    {'name':'sql'},
                                                    {'name':'flask'}
})
```

I want to filter candidates where based on skills required vs skills present for alleast 75% match or 50% match.
note : the percent can be dynamic. How should I query and filter the objects . if i enter skills like 'python','java','sql','docker'. and mention 75% match.

I also want to know how the performance will be if i have to traverse over atleast a million records.